# Xcode 6.4 code sense not working with Alamofire 1.2.3

Tags: xcode, alamofire, codesense

I use pod file to install Alamofire 1.2.3 and works well.
However, I have no idea why Xcode code sense is not working with Alamofire. Does anyone here meet the same problem like me ???

[image]

Comment: were you able to find the solution?